# Can Google campaign link open the app?

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I am integrating Google install campaign tracking in my iOS app. I have a sample link which, when clicked from an email or web page, will direct me to the iOS App Store to install, or open, the app.

But if I already have the app installed, are these links supposed to actually open the app? I do not see that action happen, I only keep going to the App Store with the "open" button. Is this the correct action? I was under the impression the link would be sent to the app to open/run right away.

[Google Analytics integration guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns#ios-url-builder)

Answer (score 0):

From what I know and from what I did for my Android APP (I think the functionality is similar on iOS), you need to broadcast an INSTALL_REFERRER intent to your application that contains some Google Analytics campaign data. This is the same intent that the Google Play Store application broadcasts to your application after it is installed by a user.

You should check if App Store does the same broadcast.

So, if it is the same routine, it won't send anything if the app is already installed :)